# All directories wrongly identified as git repos in zsh

Tags: zsh, git, oh-my-zsh

I am using zsh and Oh-My-Zsh on Ubuntu 14.04.

For some reason all directories are indicated to be git repos. This is true for all oh-my-zsh themes, which leads me to believe that this is a zsh issue perhaps related to `vcs_info`.

Comment: Is your home or root directory a git repository? If so, all of its subdirectories will be treated as git repositories as well (at least by git and oh-my-zsh seems to be calling the git executable to display information in the prompt).

Comment: `vcs_info` uses `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` to determine if you are currently in a git repository. You can use `git rev-parse --git-dir` to find out where the `.git` directory for this repository is.

Comment: Thank you both.I had somehow managed to create a git repo in /.

Comment: @Networker Do not use code markup for things that are not code. Proper names are not code.

Answer (score 2):

Any sub directory to a directory containing a git repo will be identified as a git repo. I had accidentally created a git repo in / which resulted in all directories being identified as git repos.